# Что такое "именованные кортежи" в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, терминология, кортежи

- Что такое именованные кортежи?
- Как их можно использовать?
- Где нужно использовать именованные кортежи вместо обычных?

---

<sub><sup>***P. S.** Это перевод [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python) c enSO.
Интересующихся темой "зачем делать такие переводы" прошу [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)*</sup></sub>.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python

Comment: @Danis, так написано же что этот вопрос - перевод того.

Comment: @wchistow [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/1365). Насколько это актуально и работает — трудно сказать

Comment: Хотя я что-то так и не понял чем они особо лучше просто классов. Обычно удобнее класс описать с нужными полями и функционалом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Что такое именованные кортежи?

Именованные кортежи — это кортежи.

Они могут делать все, что и обычные кортежи.

Но они — больше чем кортежи.

Это — подкласс кортежей, который программным образом создается в соответствии с вашими требованиями (именованные поля и фиксированная длина).

В следующем примере, например, создается подкласс кортежа, и не считая того, что он имеет фиксированную длину (в данном случае три), его без проблем можно использовать везде, где и обычный кортеж. Это известно как [принцип подстановки Лисков](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2).

*[Начиная с Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)* для создания именованного кортежа можно использовать определение класса [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ANamedTuple(NamedTuple):
    """строка документации"""
    foo: int
    bar: str
    baz: list
```

Пример выше аналогичен классу [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), за исключением того, что он имеет аннотации типов и строку документации. А вот это можно использовать в Python 2 и выше:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class_name = 'ANamedTuple'
>>> fields = 'foo bar baz'
>>> ANamedTuple = namedtuple(class_name, fields)
```

Пример создания экземпляра:

```
>>> ant = ANamedTuple(1, 'bar', [])
```

Проверяем его и используем атрибуты:

```
>>> ant
ANamedTuple(foo=1, bar='bar', baz=[])
>>> ant.foo
1
>>> ant.bar
'bar'
>>> ant.baz.append('anything')
>>> ant.baz
['anything']
```

### Более глубокое объяснение:

Чтобы понять концепцию именованных кортежей, нужно сначала понять, что такое кортеж. Кортеж — это, по существу, неизменяемый список (его нельзя изменить в памяти на месте).

Вот пример использования обычного кортежа:

```
>>> student_tuple = 'Lisa', 'Simpson', 'A'
>>> student_tuple
('Lisa', 'Simpson', 'A')
>>> student_tuple[0]
'Lisa'
>>> student_tuple[1]
'Simpson'
>>> student_tuple[2]
'A'
```

Его можно "развернуть" с помощью итеративной распаковки:

```
>>> first, last, grade = student_tuple
>>> first
'Lisa'
>>> last
'Simpson'
>>> grade
'A'
```

Именованные кортежи — это кортежи, которые позволяют осуществлять доступ к своим элементам по имени, а не просто через индекс!

Например, можно создать такой именованный кортеж:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Student = namedtuple('Student', ['first', 'last', 'grade'])
```

Для улучшения читабельности можно также передавать не список, а строку, включающую имена, разделенные пробелами:

```
>>> Student = namedtuple('Student', 'first last grade')
```

### Как их использовать?

С ними можно делать все, что и с обычными кортежами (смотри выше) а также следующее:

```
>>> named_student_tuple = Student('Lisa', 'Simpson', 'A')
>>> named_student_tuple.first
'Lisa'
>>> named_student_tuple.last
'Simpson'
>>> named_student_tuple.grade
'A'
>>> named_student_tuple._asdict()
OrderedDict([('first', 'Lisa'), ('last', 'Simpson'), ('grade', 'A')])
>>> vars(named_student_tuple)
OrderedDict([('first', 'Lisa'), ('last', 'Simpson'), ('grade', 'A')])
>>> new_named_student_tuple = named_student_tuple._replace(first='Bart', grade='C')
>>> new_named_student_tuple
Student(first='Bart', last='Simpson', grade='C')
```

### Когда/зачем вместо обычных кортежей следует использовать именованные?

Их можно использовать вместо объекта (если бы в противном случае вы использовали бы объект с неизменяемыми атрибутами и без функций).

Возможность добавлять функции можно осуществить через подкласс:

```
class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'x y')):
    """adding functionality to a named tuple"""
        __slots__ = ()
        @property
        def hypot(self):
            return (self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2) ** 0.5
        def __str__(self):
            return 'Point: x=%6.3f  y=%6.3f  hypot=%6.3f' % (self.x, self.y, self.hypot)
```

Comment: С достижением 2k, Глеб!

Comment: @чистов_n, спасибо) Перестану наконец надоедать вам своими правками)